# How can I use std::bitset while the number is larger than the max number of type size_t

Tags: c++, std

I declared a std::set as below:

```
std::bitset<2 ^ 160> _bitset;
```

I can use the set as

```
_bitset[10] = 1;
```

But if I wanna set the index (1 << 128) to 1

```
_bitset[(1 << 128)] = 1;
```

I got the warning:

warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
_bitset[(1 << 128)] = 1;

I know the error because of (1 << 128), it is too large.

But how can I use the number like this?

Comment: You do know that `^` is the bitwise XOR operator?

Comment: As for your problem, you do know that the template argument is the number of bits, not the maximum value of those bits? And that the index is the zero-based index of the bit? So if you want a bitset with 160 bits then that's `std::bitset<160>`. And for the 128:th bit you use index `127`.

Comment: You cannot represent numbers larger than 2^64 (on common platforms). Note that 2^64 bits are roughly  2^34 GB. That's over a billion GB. It's safe to say no PC handles this, and certainly not 2^160 bits.

Comment: What is the problem you try to solve? Do you really need 2 to the power of 160 bits (which are billions and billions of bytes)? Or do you need 160 bits (which is 20 bytes)? Perhaps you should take some time with [a `std::bitset` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a bitset that holds 160 bits (and can thus represent 2^160 different states), you should use `std::bitset<160> _bitset;`.

To set the 128th bit, you just do `_bitset[127] = 1`.

On the off-chance that you indeed want a bitset with 2^160 bits (which could theoretically hold 2^(2^160) different states): This doesn't fit into your computer, and it wouldn't even fit into a computer the size of the earth.

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I use the number like this?

No, you cannot use a number as big as `1 << 128` as index of a `std::bitset`.
`std::bitset` is a template with `std::size_t` as the parameter. While the maximum value of `std::size_t` is implementation defined, it is much less than `1 << 128`.

Note that `2 ^ 160` is 162 as `^` is [`xor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/xor) operation. So `_bitset` has only 162 bits.

And you can go upto index `161` because of zero-based indexing.

And `1 << 128` is very well beyond that.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer because at least the compiler error is about `size_t` not fitting the result `1 << 128`. Don't get me wrong, your concerns are correct, but there is a deeper problem here (mostly with OP's understanding of bitsets) than the use of the `^`.